# Does Nuget create an error log file when a package is installed?

Tags: logging, nuget, nuget-package

I have a local Nuget package that I am attempting to install.  Everything runs fine with no specific errors I can see, but about 1/2 of the tasks that need to be completed for the install don't seem to happen or do anything.

I have NuGet Package Explorer and I can fix the install if I know where to start.  Does NuGet create an error log file someplace when it does an install and where would I find it?

Thanks for the help.
Doug

Comment: Did you try to install from the NuGet console and look at "Output - Package Manager". I believe most of the logging goes there.

Comment: @AlexandreDion thanks! Your's was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Package Manager Console` to execute the install step. Log output is provided there.

Make sure that you select your `Package source` if you are installing from a local package.

Example output for a failed nuspec project below:

```
PM> Install-Package MyTestPackage
Successfully installed 'MyTestPackage 0.0.1.4'.
Successfully added 'MyTestPackage 0.0.1.4' to Test_Project.
Missing expression after unary operator '!'.
PM>
```

Example output with verbose logging below:

```
PM> Install-Package ClearlyDoesNotExistYet -Verbose
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='ClearlyDoesNotExistYet'
  OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='ClearlyDoesNotExistYet' 220ms
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'ClearlyDoesNotExistYet'
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can increase the log level ? I get an error when installing a package but the error message doesn't contain much information.

Comment: If you add the -Verbose parameter (case-sensitive!), you'll be able to see which repository is being queried (example added to my answer).